# Javascript getElementById undefined

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to click add button to insert new `<p>` element into `<div id="output">`. When I click delete button, it should delete the `<p>` element that I just append into div output. My problem is that `var outputArea = document.getElementById("output");` is undefined sometimes.

For example, when I click the delete button, it may not have any response, but the second times I click the button, it will work.

```js
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("add").onclick = addParagraph;
    document.getElementById("delete").onclick = deleteLastParagraph;    
}

function deleteLastParagraph() {
    var outputArea = document.getElementById("output");
    var numberOfParas = document.getElementById("output").childElementCount;
    if (outputArea.childNodes[0] == null) {
        alert("No paragraph delete!");
    }
    // outputArea.removeChild(outputArea.childNodes[0]);
    outputArea.removeChild(outputArea.childNodes[numberOfParas - 1]);
}


function addParagraph() {
    var textToAdd = document.getElementById("input").value;
    var outputArea = document.getElementById("output");
    var paragraph = document.createElement("p");
    paragraph.innerHTML = textToAdd;
    outputArea.appendChild(paragraph);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="task4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style>
        #output {
            border: blue 5px solid;
            padding: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            margin-top: 10px;
            width: 50%;
        }

        #output p {
            padding: 10px;
            border: black 1px dashed;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h2> Creating, Appending and Deleting Nodes in the DOM Tree </h2>
<p> Type in text below, click add to add as paragraph.
    <button id="add"> ADD</button>
</p>
<textarea id="input" rows="10" cols="60">
</textarea><br>
<button id="delete">Delete Last Paragraph</button>
<br><br>
<h2> Added Paragraphs </h2>
<div id="output">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because *childElementCount* counts the number of *elements*, but *childNodes* includes all nodes (compare *childElementCount* and *childNodes.length*). There is a text node because of the space between the opening and closing DIV tags.

Comment: this is my answer in this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53040623/dom-nodes-adding-deleting-alerts/53041036#53041036)... i think that it is help you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer in this post i think that help you ([DOM Nodes Adding, Deleting, Alerts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53040623/dom-nodes-adding-deleting-alerts/53041036#53041036)) ... there are the code with same your target question and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt see any major issues while just running the code as is with basic text input.
This leads me to believe your issue may be due to using innerHTML to set the content of your p tags. innerHTML allows for any html in your input to render as html instead of as text, this could be breaking the document in weird ways.  Try using [Node.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) to set the text instead.

You also need to return after your alert statement to avoid throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my remedy for the problem:

```
function deleteLastParagraph() {
    var outputArea = document.getElementById("output");
    var lastChild = outputArea.lastChild
    if(lastChild) outputArea.removeChild(lastChild);
    else alert('No child nodes to remove')
}
```

The problem was that childNodes property sometimes higher than the childCount hence the problem with lack of response after button click.